# Exposing a public kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

If I were to create a public Kafka cluster that accepts messages from multiple clients, but are purely processed by a separate backend. What would be the right way to design it?

A bit more concrete example, let's say I have 50 kafka brokers. How do I:

1. Configure clients without the manually adding in IPs of the 50 kafka brokers.?
2. Loadbalancing messages to kafka broker based on load if possible.
3. Easier/automated way to setup additional clients with quota.

Comment: You never needed to add all brokers to clients to begin with. This seems to be more a scaling question than "exposing to the public" which implies you're opening connections to the internet

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use hashicorp consul which is one of the open source service discovery tools to get your kafka brokers on, ultimately you will have single endpoint and you don't need to add multiple brokers in your clients. There are several other open source told available
2. There are few ways, use kafka assigner tool to balance the traffic or kafka cruise control open source tool to automatically balance the cluster for you